# Monitor ASP.NET Session State

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Is there any way to monitor asp.net session state in order to watch object size, or is there any other practice to find out a way to lighten asp.net session?

Comment: You can always use good old' Perfmon. Plenty of performance counters for the ASP.NET Session (timeouts, unique sessions, expired sessions, etc)

Comment: I 'd like to use a detailed overview of session state and counters at performance monitor are not that detailed (showing objects and size of them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using sessionMode="SqlServer" you could just query the database.  Or you could write an IHttpModule to log, on each request, the current number and size of objects in the SessionStore for each user.

Comment: I guess if you running a state server (service) you can switch to sql database for debug and then turn it back. Thanks